# Treatment as a fixed effect in a non-linear mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-models

I would like to fit a nonlinear mixed model and then test differences between parameters in treatment and control groups.

I am using nlmer from the lme4 package.
I am using the Oranges dataset as test data for this problem. 
The circumferences of 5 trees are measured over time. Each tree exhibits logistic growth. In the basic example, we include Tree as a random effect. 
I have extended the data so that there is a treat and control group (the treat is just a copy of control with circumference values doubled).
My problem is, I'd like to have 'treat' as a fixed effect and then test the differences between the non-linear model parameter Asym in the treatment and control groups.

```r
   library(lme4)

   #Toy data based on Orange (lme4)
   # Create a copy of Orange data, double the circumference values, make new labels for trees (no. 6-10) and label all as treatment (1)
   Orange.with.treatment<-Orange
   Orange.with.treatment$circumference<-Orange.with.treatment$circumference*2
   Orange.with.treatment$Tree <- as.factor(as.numeric(Orange.with.treatment$Tree) + 5)
   Orange.with.treatment$treat<- as.factor(rep(1,length(Orange$Tree)))

   # Create a copy of Orange data and label all as control (1)
   Orange.control<-Orange
   Orange.control$treat<- as.factor(rep(0,length(Orange$Tree)))

   # combine into one dataframe
   Orange.full<-(rbind(Orange.control,Orange.with.treatment))


   # a nlmer fit not considering treatment as a factor
   startvec <- c(Asym = 200, xmid = 725, scal = 350)
   (nm1 <- nlmer(circumference ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, xmid, scal) ~ Asym|Tree,
                Orange.full, start = startvec))

   # a nlmer fit considering treatment as a fixed factor?
   startvec <- c(Asym = 200, xmid = 725, scal = 350)
   (nm2 <- nlmer(circumference ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, xmid, scal) ~ Asym+treat|Tree,
                Orange.full, start = startvec))

   # test differences in parameters between treat and control?
```

I have tried adding treat alongside Asym in the formula, but I don;t think that is correct.
What I would like is a summary of Asym in treat and control, and a way to statistically test the difference between them.

Comment: I'd use `nlme`. Something like `nlme(circumference ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, xmid, scal), data = Orange.full,
    fixed = Asym + xmid + scal ~ treat, random = Asym + xmid + scal ~ 1 | Tree,
    start = c(200, 200, 725, 0, 350, 0), control = nlmeControl(msMaxIter = 1000))`.

Comment: The `summary` will give you p-values for the treatment differences.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Roland!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be open to using other tools, here is an `nlme` solution:

```
library(nlme)
mod <- nlme(circumference ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, xmid, scal), data = Orange.full,
    fixed = Asym + xmid + scal ~ treat, random = Asym + xmid + scal ~ 1 | Tree,
    start = c(200, 200, 725, 0, 350, 0), control = nlmeControl(msMaxIter = 1000))
summary(mod)

#Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
#  Model: circumference ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, xmid, scal) 
# Data: Orange.full 
#       AIC      BIC    logLik
#  608.9452 638.1756 -291.4726
#
#Random effects:
# Formula: list(Asym ~ 1, xmid ~ 1, scal ~ 1)
# Level: Tree
# Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
#                 StdDev   Corr         
#Asym.(Intercept) 43.23426 As.(I) xm.(I)
#xmid.(Intercept) 38.35359 -0.031       
#scal.(Intercept) 32.49873 -0.968  0.279
#Residual         11.27260              
#
#Fixed effects: Asym + xmid + scal ~ treat 
#                    Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
#Asym.(Intercept) 191.2135  22.30629 55  8.572177  0.0000
#Asym.treat1      193.0409  31.56922 55  6.114847  0.0000
#xmid.(Intercept) 722.4272  53.37976 55 13.533729  0.0000
#xmid.treat1        5.0466  62.02158 55  0.081368  0.9354
#scal.(Intercept) 349.4497  41.68009 55  8.384092  0.0000
#scal.treat1        7.3181  48.41709 55  0.151146  0.8804
#
#<snip>
```

As you see, this shows a significant treatment effect on the asymptote but not on the other parameters, as expected.